# ¿Cómo calcular distancia entre puntos y líneas?

Tags: algoritmos, matemáticas

Tengo un `shapefile` con puntos que corresponden a inmuebles y en otro `shapefile` tengo líneas que corresponden a vías ferroviarias.

¿Cómo puedo obtener la distancia entre el punto y la línea más cercana?

Comment: Hola Debianitas. Esta pregunta es demasiado amplia. Has de explicar mejor tu situación. Y sobre todo has de intentarlo y mostrarnos qué problemas concretos o errores tienes. Si no lo has intentado, investiga primero. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Hola @lois6b realmente llevo unos dias buscando informacion pero nada se adapta a los que estoy buscando, no eh podido comenzar el proyecto ya que no se como encararlo. Saludos

Comment: Nada de lo que has encontrado sirve?  Explica mejor tu caso para ver el tipo de datos en Shapefile y ejemplos de resultados esperados. Mira los enlaces de mis comentarios. un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero debes encontrar la distancia mas corta entre cada recta y el punto. Hay dos métodos.

Primero:
Para ello debes buscar el plano perpendicular al vector director de cada vía y que pase por el punto que te da el enunciado (si no te dan nada todo son variables). Encontramos la intersección entre la recta y el plano, esto nos dará el punto que esté situado más cerca del otro punto. Finalmente calculamos la distancia entre estos dos puntos con la siguiente fórmula: 
dist(A,B)=sqrt((b1-a1)^2+(b2-a2)^2+(b3-a3)^2).

Hasta aquí todo son cálculos con variables por lo que principalmente no debería haber ningún problema al pasarlo a Python. Haces lo mismo con el otro raíl.

La segunda opción es más viable en cuanto a los cálculos con ordenador pero el procedimiento es el mismo: 
distancia(Punto,recta)=Producto vectorial(vector director recta X vector formado por un punto de la recta y el otro punto)/módulo vector director recta.
Calculas los mismo con la otra recta.

Finalmente,con el condicional, preguntas que distancia es más grande.

if dist(a,b)>dist(A,B):

......

else:

.......

Es complejo explicarlo de forma genérica, espero haberte ayudado.